# Angular 9 - Singleton Service

Tags: angular, service

I'm trying to create a Singleton service in Angular 9 which a component relies on for displaying data, and another component updates the data in the service.

I've been following Docs on Angular's site, but I cannot get it to work as intended. I am seeing the following behavior:

1. Component 1 invokes Service, updates data
2. Change is not seen on Component 2

When I update the data in Component 1, I want to see the change reflected in Component 2.

**Service**

```
    @Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
    export class SampleService{
    private data: any[] = [];
    
    public get Data: any[]{
        return this.data;
    }
    
    public addData(toAdd: any){
        this.data.push(toAdd);
    }
}
```

**Component 1 - Updating Data:**

```
    export class Component1{

    constructor(private sampleService: SampleService) {}

    .
    .
    .
    
    private manipulateData(){
        this.sampleService.addData("test");
    }
}
```

**Component 2 - Displaying Data:**

```
@Component({
  template: '<p>{{sampleService.Data}}</p>',
})
export class Component2{
    constructor(private sampleService: SampleService) {}
}
```

Comment: are you using onpush strategy on component2? and should be d of data be small in component 2?

Comment: I recommend using a BehaviorSubject on the Service for this

Comment: @enno.void I implemented BehaviorSubject as suggested, and now see the data as intended! However, (this might need to be in a separate question) the data is not being updated in a mat-table -- it's just empty